# ¿Cómo actualizar la fecha de actualización automáticamente en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla de MySQL con con campo de creación y uno de actualización, lo que deseo es que **cada vez** que se actualice la información de un registro de esta tabla, la columna de `fecha_actualizacion` sea actualizada automáticamente.

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS eventos (
  evento_id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nombre VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  fecha_creacion TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
  fecha_actualizacion TIMESTAMP NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Mi problema es que el campo `fecha_actualizacion` sólo se actualiza la primera vez que modifico el registro, pero no las próximas veces.

¿Hay una manera de actualizar esta información sin tener que incluir un

```sql
SET fecha_actualizacion = NOW()
```

cada que actualizo esta información?

Comment: probaste con un trigger?

Comment: disculpa, ¿A qué te refieres?

Answer (score 3):

Crea un trigger de este modo

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER actualiza AFTER UPDATE ON tuTabla
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE tuTabla SET old.fecha_actualizacion = NOW();
END;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

La intención es que este disparador entre en funcionamiento antes o después de algún evento en tu tabla

> Así que una vez que ocurra una actualización en tu tabla se ejecute el trigger por cada fila, actualizando el valor viejo o que ya existe por el de la función now()

La instrucción `FOR EACH ROW` será la encargada de que está rutina actúe sobre cada fila afectada