# Actualizar toda una tabla de una DB al modificar un valor de otra tabla

Tags: php, mysql

> Tengo lo siguiente:

**Una tabla de Ingredientes con sus campos**

- id
- nombre
- unidad de medida
- precio

**Luego tengo una tabla de Viandas**

- id
- nombre
- id_cliente
- costo
- tipo

**Y finalmente una tabla que las relaciona a ambas MenuIngre**

- id_vianda
- id_ingrediente
- cantidad

**Tengo este método que edita los Ingredientes en la base de datos**

```
  /*============================================
    EDITAR INGREDIENTE
    ============================================*/

    static public function mdlEditarIngrediente($tabla, $datos){


        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("UPDATE $tabla SET id_unidad = :id_unidad, nombre = :nombre, precio = :precio WHERE id = :id");   

        $stmt->bindParam(":nombre", $datos["nombre"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":id_unidad", $datos["id_unidad"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":precio", $datos["precio"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":id", $datos["id"], PDO::PARAM_STR);


        if($stmt->execute()){

            return "ok";

        }else{
            return "error";
        }

        $stmt -> close();

        $stmt = null;



    }
```

**Y este otro método que actualiza las viandas**

```
 /*============================================
        EDITAR VIANDA
        ============================================*/

        static public function mdlEditarVianda($tabla, $datos){


            $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("UPDATE $tabla SET nombre = :nombre, id_cliente = :id_cliente,  costo = :costo, dmc = :dmc WHERE id = :id");   

            $stmt->bindParam(":nombre", $datos["nombre"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(":id_cliente", $datos["id_cliente"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(":costo", $datos["costo"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(":dmc", $datos["dmc"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(":id", $datos["id"], PDO::PARAM_STR);


            if($stmt->execute()){
                                        $tabla2 = "menuingre";
                                        $datosJson = json_decode($datos["productos"], true);

                                        $id_vianda = $datos["id"];

                                        // Elimino todos los "menuingre" correspondientes a esta vianda
                                            $eliminar = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("DELETE FROM $tabla2 WHERE id_vianda = $id_vianda");
                                            $eliminar->bindParam(":id_vianda", $id_vianda, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                                            $eliminar->execute();


                                         foreach($datosJson as $value){

                                            $id_ingrediente = $value["id"];
                                            $cantidad = $value["cantidad"];

                                            $insertarMenuIngr = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla2(id_ingrediente, id_vianda, cantidad) VALUES (:id_ingrediente, :id_vianda, :cantidad)");

                                            $insertarMenuIngr->bindParam(":id_ingrediente", $id_ingrediente, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                                            $insertarMenuIngr->bindParam(":id_vianda", $id_vianda, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                                            $insertarMenuIngr->bindParam(":cantidad", $cantidad, PDO::PARAM_STR);

                                            $insertarMenuIngr -> execute();

                                         }

                        return "ok";



                    $stmt -> close();

                    $stmt = null;


                } else {return "error"; }
                }
```

> LO QUE ESTOY BUSCANDO ES QUE, AL MODIFICAR UN PRECIO DE UN INGREDIENTE, SE ACTUALICEN AUTOMATICAMENTE LOS CAMPOS **costo** CORRESPONDIENTE A CADA MENU QUE TENGA EL INGREDIENTE.

No bien como encararlo, cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.

Comment: Eso pareciera mas tema de un trigger, ¿has tratado algo al respecto?

Comment: No, ni se de que se trata, pero al menos me tiraste una pista, je. A google

Comment: Checa si [esta respuesta te ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/328199/c%c3%b3mo-actualizar-la-fecha-de-actualizaci%c3%b3n-autom%c3%a1ticamente-en-mysql/328207#328207) o [esta otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/319351/realizar-un-trigger-de-historial/319384#319384)

Comment: En mi caso, que quiero actualizar la tabla Viandas luego de actualizar la tabla Ingredientes, el codigo del trigger donde deberia ponerlo? En la funcion mdlEditarIngrediente luego de cerrar la conexion?

Comment: No  @Mani, los triggers se crean desde el gestor de bases de datos y existen ahi, se invocan after o before en una tabla, te recomiendo [leas mas al respecto](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Comment: Te agradezco, entendi lo que tengo que crear, la cosa es la siguiente: Yo una vez que modifique el precio del ingrediente tengo que buscar cada vianda que tenga este ingrediente, y ahora tengo que ir a buscar cada una de estas viandas completas (es decir, tengo que traer todos los ingredientes con sus cantidades), luego hacer uso de la tabla ingredientes para ver unidades de medida y precios de cada uno, hacer operaciones matematicas e insertar este valor en el campo "costo" de cada vianda. Tengo que hacer todo eso (y ademas se puede hacer?) con lenguaje de SQL? Creo que quiero morir, ja

Comment: Efectivamente con un trigger puedes hacerlo , aquí te dejo un link. https://www.anerbarrena.com/create-trigguer-mysql-5145/